# preciso colocar um left join a mais nessa query

Tags: mysql, join

O meu código está abaixo
ele me retorna "h.banco as banco" com um numero, que é chave estrangeira
eu quero que ele tb me retorne a descricao deste banco, só que em muitos casos, o h.banco me retorna como `null`

como eu monto a cláusula from para isso?
tentei colocar mais um `left join` só que ele me retornou o mesmo registro repetidas vezes

```
    select a.numero,
       a.competencia,
       d.area as setor,
       c.nome as nomeprojeto,
       e.especificacao as elemento,
       e.codigo as codigoelemento,
       f.descricao as rubr,
       f.rubrica as codigorubrica,
       a.valorestimado,
       a.observacao,
       a.fonterecurso codigofonte,
       g.descricao fonte,
       a.competenciadespesa,
       h.nome as credor ,
       h.documento as doccredor,
       h.tipopessoa as tipocredor,
       h.banco as banco,
       h.contacorrente as contacorrente,
       h.agencia as agencia,
       a.processo,
       a.finalidade as objetoSad,
       a.datainclusao,
       a.datamod
from  sad a left join credor h on a.credor = h.codigo,
      cronograma b,
      projeto c,
      organograma d,
      elementodespesa e,
      rubrica f,
      fonterecurso g
where a.cronograma = b.codigo
  and b.projeto  = c.codigo
  and c.organograma = d.codigo
  and b.rubrica = f.codigo
  and f.elementodespesa = e.codigo
  and a.fonterecurso = g.codigo
  and a.codigo = 1954
```

Comment: Há algumas inconsistências neste seu SQL. A primeira, você teria que adicionar cada left join ao seu lugar, cada linha, um left, outra coisa... com base no que você está unindo as tabelas organograma, elementodespesa, fonterecurso, qual campo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz algumas modificações no seu código e baseado nisso aconselho que revise os mesmos, da forma que utiliza pode gerar muitas inconsistências, como por exemplo registros repetidos e demora no retorno dos dados. O Uso do "Left Join" prevalece o campo à esquerda, portanto sempre que quiser utilizar mais de uma tabela, ele é mais aconselhável ao invés de inserir o nome das tabelas no "from". Outro quesito importante para que seu select tenha mais performance é a ordem dos tipos de campos no "select". Sugiro seguir esta ordem: "Integer, Date, Time, Numeric, String" independente da ordem das tabelas no "Left". Acrescente o campo em questão que deseja obter no "select" e teste o código abaixo e depois informe se o resultado é o esperado.

```
select a.numero,
       a.competencia,
       d.area as setor,
       c.nome as nomeprojeto,
       e.especificacao as elemento,
       e.codigo as codigoelemento,
       f.descricao as rubr,
       f.rubrica as codigorubrica,
       a.valorestimado,
       a.observacao,
       a.fonterecurso codigofonte,
       g.descricao fonte,
       a.competenciadespesa,
       h.nome as credor,
       h.documento as doccredor,
       h.tipopessoa as tipocredor,
       h.banco as banco,
       h.contacorrente as contacorrente,
       h.agencia as agencia,
       a.processo,
       a.finalidade as objetoSad,
       a.datainclusao,
       a.datamod
from sad a
where (a.codigo = 1954)
left join credor h on (a.credor = h.codigo)
left join cronograma b on (a.cronograma = b.codigo)
left join projeto c on (b.projeto = c.codigo)
left join organograma d on (c.organograma = d.codigo)
left join rubrica f on (b.rubrica = f.codigo)
left join elementodespesa e on (f.elementodespesa = e.codigo)
left join fonterecurso g on (a.fonterecurso = g.codigo)
```

Nota: Para um retorno mais rápido no seu "select", aconselho que estude também a ordem das condições na cláusula "where", a ordem é sempre do mais provável ao menos improvável.